# Detect when a new image is uploaded to my server

Tags: 8, files

I have created a custom app that will allow logged in users to upload an image which will be automatically uploaded to my web server through SFTP method.

Is there a module or even programmatically possible to detect from my Drupal 8 site that there is new image uploaded to the directory `../sites/files/app-images/` of my server and retrieve the name of that image ?

Comment: I’d think you’d be better off looking at an entity save/create event instead. Are these File entities or Media?

Comment: @Kevin It is a simple image (.jpeg) just uploaded to my server using a mobile app ! It is not a file entity.

Comment: A possible solution is to create a custom module which runs with each cron that scans this folder and creates Media Images out of the uploaded images. Of course you'll need to check whether the uploaded image is already in the database to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @Ismail Cherri I thought about the cron method but isn't a performance issue to run the cron every 5 seconds to check for a new uploaded image ? Since I need to know about the uploaded image as soon as it will be uploaded to my server !

Comment: In this case, the upload should be done through Drupal itself not through SFTP, or at least create an endpoint in Drupal which creates the Media entity after the upload is done

Comment: @Ismail Cherri, **least create an endpoint in Drupal which creates the Media entity after the upload is done**, this what i am looking for ! How can I detect that the upload is done ? How to detect when whatever image is done uploading to my server ?